# kivy ScrollView fit to Window

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I followed the kivy Scrollview tutorial in the kivy docs. But it leaves a lot of space on the right of the window. I want the Scrollview to fit to the Screen when resized.

This is what I got:

```
 from kivy.app import App
 from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
 from kivy.uix.button import Button
 from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

 class ScrollViewApp(App):
     def build(self):

         layout = GridLayout(cols=1,
                        size_hint=(None,None),width=700)
         layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter("height"))

         for i in range(30):
             btn = Button(text=str(i),size=(480,40),size_hint=(None,None))
             layout.add_widget(btn)

         root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1,1)) 
         root.add_widget(layout)

         return root

 if __name__ == ("__main__"):
 ScrollViewApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, I'm pretty sure the ScrollView *does* fill the Window (this is the expected, automatic behaviour) but that the GridLayout and Buttons you have placed in it have a fixed size so nothing visually changes when the window size is changed.

If you want the buttons to fill the window horizontally, just set size_hint_x to None (rather than both components as you have done) for both the Buttons and the GridLayout.